# Headphone jack/logic board broken?

Tags: macbook-pro

Recently, my headphone jack on my macbook pro has been very loose. I could easily just tap the wire and the headphone jack would disconnect the wire. So what I did was put some aluminum foil inside the jack. **stupid me**. Because I stuck too much in there, and I stuck it in real deep, and a pin or a needle can barely even reach it.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Update:

---

I got it out! Yay. However now, here are two problems I am having:

1) My speakers don't work and the adjust volume option is greyed out, went to system preferences but nothing in output

2) Works with earphones/external speakers but only the left ear works (for both my external speakers and earphones)

3) Occasionally there is a red light in the headphone jack when nothing is inserted in it

4) Its also worth mentioning that these three keys: p, caps lock and mute do not function and are not recognized on my computer and have not been working for a while.

Is there is something wrong with my logic board?

Answer (score 2):

You're absolutely right, stupid you.

Jokes aside, if you have the MBP with removable battery, remove it. Turn your computer off, and get a long needle, match, miniature tweezer, unbent paperclip, straw, or pretty much any long, thin pretty strong appliance with a tip able to "hook" on to the aluminium foil. Try to get it out.

There really isn't much more to do. If you can't get it out, you'll either need to send it in for service, or open the Mac and replace the headphone jack yourself (warranty break deluxe).

Keep trying, maybe use a weak suction device or compressed air, be patient, and you'll hopefully get it out. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, this helped and I got it out, however I may have caused a bigger problem! Check my update.

Comment: Oh dear. I'd definitely turn it in for service if I were you, it seems something went pretty wrong, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you learned a not so expensive repair lesson.

Putting a aluminum foil inside would short the circuits since Al-foil is conductive.

Furthermore using conductive tools like needles would just do further damages.

How far is the damage can be only guessed, or try running the Apple Hardware Test to see.

Unfortunately you might have to brig you computer to a repair shop.

*PS:
Do not stick needles in the wall power outlets.*

**Edit**:

As you describe your problems and if you are lucky it is only some al-foil residue left in the plug shorting the plug. Try using a tooth brush like this to clean it.

[image]

So you know what is happening, here is a cross section of a jack plug showing tiny contacts (that are spring-loaded). So chances are some of you foil got in it.
[image]

Comment: Shorting pins across an audio jack isn't that bad. Headphones by nature have a VERY low resistance, so they're not much different from the tinfoil.

Answer (score 0):

> 1) My speakers don't work and the adjust volume option is greyed out,
>   went to system preferences but nothing in output
>
> ...
>
> 3) Occasionally there is a red light in the headphone jack when
>   nothing is inserted in it

For these 2 issues, the digital (optical) audio connection is responsible. The red light is used for optical signalling, which is enabled when the jack senses the presence of an object in the jack, but the electronics confirm it's not headphones. This issue isn't too uncommon, and can generally be "reset" back to the off state by resetting PRAM. Also try inserting and removing a headphone plug a few times.